# Dual citizen living in the US: What can I do to avoid using the US passport when applying for a Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, china, us-citizens, dual-nationality, irish-citizens

I have to apply for a Chinese visa to go on my trip to China, in July 2015. I am a dual citizen with Ireland and the US. I want to use my Irish passport for various reasons, but the main on being that it's quite a bit cheaper on the Irish passport. I read online that if you show them a US passport when applying, when proving you have the right to be in the US, the consulate employee will make you get it on the US passport. What can I do to get it on the Irish passport, successfully. Should I say I need my US passport to get back into the country when I go on another trip? Have you experienced this before? What did you do?

Comment: You could go to Canada or any other country on your Irish passport and apply for the Chinese visa there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

China's visa rules are rather simple in this matter, if you are applying for a visa in a country other than your citizenship, then you need to show proof that you are residing / traveling legally in that country.  If you can not prove that you are in the USA legally using your Irish passport, then you have no choice but to apply with your US passport.

While you could try the excuse that you are leaving on another trip and can't leave your US passport behind.  But there is a good chance they will levy the USA fee, even though they are stamping the visa in your Irish passport.

Comment: So in other words, I'll have no luck with avoiding the fee and should just use the US one off the bat?

Comment: It never hurts to ask. Just be prepared to bite the bullet and go the more expensive US citizen route.

Comment: To consider: You need to leave and return the USA on the same passport. If you return on your Irish passport, will they let you in without trouble? With US security being as ridiculous as it is today, I'd try hard to avoid anything that could cause trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729: What passport one enters and leaves the U.S. with is independent of what passport one enters and leaves China with.

Comment: Can't you show them your US driving license and your Irish passport? If you chose to apply through a travel agency, couldn't it help? (These are just ideas, I've got no personal experience with it.)

Comment: @gnasher729 the US immigration authorities do not check passports on exit.  You don't need to show anybody your US passport until you return to the US.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the visa you are getting, you are eligible (thanks Obama and Xi Jinping!) for a 10 year tourist visa for 140 dollars. However, the period of which you are allowed to be in the country maybe is only 6 months. Overall validity of that tourist visa should be 10 years though, of course if the Chinese consulate deems you to not be a spy, have averse intentions, clean background, etc.

Look it up, it really exists as of a few months ago. Not sure if the Irish passport, or even any other countries with such a bilateral relation allows the same privileges.

Comment: single entry to China from Ireland costs €40 (albeit applying from Chinese Embassy, Dublin)